# Linking automatically generated array of buttons to a common event handler in VB.NET 2010

Tags: vb.net

I am doing a project using VB.net , where I generate an array of around 300 buttons (Number of buttons decided based on the available X&Y direction limits.) with the click of a button called START button. I defined a sub program to generate buttons using ADD Button and its successfully done.

Now I wanted to link all these buttons to same click handler automatically. I cant select the buttons and link them to a same click event because all these buttons are only generated at the time of code execution.

I am attaching my code below, It will be a great thing some one can suggest me a solution.

```
Public Class Form1

    'Variable that holds the value of button size 
    Dim buttonwidth As Integer = 40
    Dim buttonheight As Integer = 40

    Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)     Handles MyBase.Load



    Private Sub AddButton(ByVal xp As Integer, ByVal yp As Integer)

        'This routine generate button automatically
        'This routine need an inputs of its location

        'defining b as a new BUTTON control "b = New Button"
        Dim b As New Button

        'defining location as a POINT variable, which have X & Y. Taking them from the argument
        Dim location As New Point(xp, yp)

        'Assigning that location for the button
        b.Location = location

        'Assiging the size of the button
        b.Size = New Size(40, 40)

        'Giving width value to button width variable
        'buttonwidth = 40 'b.Size.Width
        'Giving height value to buttonheight variable
        'buttonheight = 40 ' b.Size.Height

        'Assigning Random label for the button
        Randomize()                                         'Initializing the random generator
        Dim label As Integer = CInt(Int((9 * Rnd() + 0)))   'Create a random number for Label
        b.Text = label                                      'Assign that number to label

        'Assigning font for the button
        b.Font = New Font(b.Font.FontFamily, 15)
        'b.Handle = New (b.Handle, Button1_Click )

        'Finally ADD the button to the form
        Me.Controls.Add(b)

    End Sub

    Private Sub Start_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Start.Click
        'This part of algorithm handles the generation and placement of buttons
        'Here x & y are two indigers responsible for the x , y cordinates of buttons

        'defining y value and it starts from cordinate 60. This can be changes to increase the spacing
        'between top border of the form and buttons

        'Here set the limits for the buttons
        Dim x_min_limit, y_min_limit, x_max_limit, y_max_limit As Integer
        x_min_limit = 60
        x_max_limit = 1300
        y_min_limit = 150
        y_max_limit = 600

        Dim y As Integer = y_min_limit         'assigning minimum limit value to y

        'This loop is responsible for generating buttons in between the limits of x&y 
        'Here the for loop executes untill the x&y reaches up to its maximum limits
        ' here x is the integer looping between the limits with a step of button width (when ever button width changes , the step also will change)
        '1.4 value deducted from step because we dont wanted to overlap 2 buttons in x axis
        For x As Integer = x_min_limit To x_max_limit Step buttonwidth - 1.4

            If x > x_max_limit - 50 Then            'This if loop makes sure that buttons are populated on y direction
                x = x_min_limit                     'If x direction population exceeds the xiven x limit, it increases the y value and restores x value to initial value        
                y = y + buttonheight - 1.4          'Y value increased with a step of button height and correction value is also given
                If y > y_max_limit Then             'whenever the Y value reaches its maximum limit, 
                    Exit For                        'terminate the whole for loop
                End If
            End If

            'Whenever the x and y coordinates get finalized ADD that button to form
            'Call the function and pass the x&y value in to it
            Call AddButton(x, y)
        Next
        Randomize()                                         'Initializing the random generator
        Dim label As Integer = CInt(Int((9 * Rnd() + 0)))   'Create a random number for Label
        Label1.Text = label


    End Sub


    Private Sub Button1_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles buttons_click



    End Sub


End Class
```

Comment: Have you tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx. You'll want to do it when you instantiate each button.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are looking for the AddHandler method: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598898(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you have to create a `Buttons_Click` Sub without `Handles` keyword, just likes follow

```
Private Sub Buttons_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs)

End Sub
```

And, you have to add event handler after creating the button objects,

```
'defining b as a new BUTTON control "b = New Button"
Dim b As New Button
AddHandler b.Click, AddressOf Buttons_Click
```

That's it.

For more references, as mention in the comments and other answers
Please go to 
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms598898%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1